# Tkinter window not displaying until after program is run

Tags: python, tkinter, text

```
global window
window = Tk()
window.geometry('300x200')
window.minsize(300,200)
window.maxsize(300,200)
window.configure(bg='black')
window.title("testupdate")

global outputtext
outputtext = tk.StringVar()
outputtext.set("starting window...")

my_label = tk.Label(window, textvariable = outputtext, bg = 'black', fg = 'white', font = 'terminal')
my_label.pack()

class ChangeLabel():
    def __init__(self, text):
        outputtext = tk.StringVar()
        outputtext.set(text)
        my_label.config(textvariable = outputtext)
```

Here's the main code: https://replit.com/@YourPetFinch/textadventure#main.py

I've been trying to make a text adventure game with Tkinter so I can package it all nicely as an app. I created a function that I can call from another file to update a label as the game output so I can keep the GUI setup simple, but I've been having a problem where the window won't show up until the code has finished running. I'm new to tkinter (and honestly not very good at Python in general) so this is probably a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `global` is used.  The `global` statement is only used inside a function, to state that you're going to modify a global.  You can't actually make a global that crosses files, but your `from gui import *` will handle that.

The issue here is understanding event-driven programming.  When you create a window, nothing gets drawn.  All that does is send a number of messages to signal the core.  The messages will not get fetched and dispatched until it gets into the `.mainloop()`.  The main loop processes all the messages and does the drawing, which might queue up more messages.

So, you cannot use `time.sleep(2)` like that.  As you saw, that will interrupt the process and prevent any drawing from being done.  Instead, you will have to use `window.after` to request a callback after some number of seconds.  The `.mainloop` monitors the timers, and will give you a call when time runs out.  You cannot use `time.sleep` inside an event handler either, for the same reason; your GUI will freeze until your event handler returns.